# Putting input in string JS

Tags: javascript, html

*I'm just a begginer, so sorry if my question seems stupid to you. I'm trying to create website with simple math tasks for a young lady.*

I created an array in js witch i try to draw random equation from. Each has a gap in different place. Problem is that im not able to define varible that would have displayed result i want to achieve.

Thats example of what i want to look like:

```
from 4+_=15 to (bellow)
4+<input id="gap" type="text">=15
```

I'm trying to fill "_" with input field. I'll show you scraps of my code to help you understand:

```
var equation= new Array(2)
equation[0] ='4+_=15';
equation[1]= '2+9:3='box'';

var random= Math.floor(Math.random()*1);

var random_equation = equation[random];
equation1= random_equation;
var eq_length = main_equation.length;

function draw_equation(){
    document.getElementById("board").innerHTML= equation1;
}
 var box = document.getElement.ById("board").innerHTML='<input id="gap" type="text">;
```

You obviusly can't define var like i did there with the "box" but that may help you understand what i mean.

So my question: Is that doable in js? I definately see cases of using this type of structure but i can't see how its made based on sources.

Comment: `document.getElementById("board").innerHTML= equation1.replace('_', '<input id="gap" type="text">')`

Comment: Thanks, alot!!! You are genius :)

Answer (score -2):

I think you shouldn't fill you text field width _. Instead of that you should make you text field seems like you need width CSS. Try this:

```
<style>
input#gap {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20px;
}
</style>
<div>4+<input id="gap" type="text">=15</div>
```